Number of Patients in ICU based on Probability (Brainteaser)
I came across the following brainteaser question (also here online):

The monthly hospital electric bill in thousands of dollars follows the
square root function of the number of patients in the ICU. The
probability of this month's electric bill being a maximum of $20,000
is 5/16.
How many patients are in the ICU?

I am not entirely sure how to approach it but it also seems that we need to make some assumptions in the setup, though I could not figure it out. Here are some thoughts:

If the maximum bill is \$20k, then the maximum number of ICU patients is 400 ( $20^2$).
If the question is looking for an expectation, would we have to assume some probability distribution with support $[0, 20]$, corresponding to the \$-bill?
The question had 4 possible choices: 40, 110, 120, 160.

Note: the answer on the link I posted seems to be an AI generated answer, with the answer being 16 (opening it in incognito does the job for me) but it goes along these lines: $E=k\sqrt{P}$, where $E$ is the electric bill and $P$ is the number of patients. From the info, we have $20=k\sqrt{P}$, i.e. $P=\left(\frac{20}{k}\right)^2$. Then

Given that the probability is 5/16, we can infer that the number of patients in the ICU is a specific value that fits this probability.
To find the exact number of patients, we can use the fact that the probability is 1. This implies that the number of patients in the ICU is a value that, when substituted into the equation, satisfies the probability condition.


Can't read official answer.  Please add Addendum to your answer, where you add the official answer, line by line.  This will facilitate some MathSE reviewer reverse-engineering the problem composer's thinking.

There is no official answer (as the test provider wouldn't show) but I added the 4 possible choices if that helps.

I went to this link which does provide step-by-step analysis.  However, the webpage prevents me from reading it, because I decline to sign up for the  webpage.  So, if feasible, I am asking you to report the analysis given in the webpage, line-by-line, directly in your posted question.

I see what you mean now. I have updated the question but would caution that it seems to be AI-generated and that the answer provided (16) was not one of the choices I had in the test.

Did AI write this question too? I'm struggling to come up with an interpretation of this question that renders it answerable. You might as well ask "What is the doctor's name?" ¶ The answer is total gibberish to me.

One could only speculate... The question did come up in the online test as described in the post without any further information and I am just as confused!

What online test? Is it something you can safely ignore? There are a lot of garbage "online tests" out there.

An online assessment for a quant research job. The problem with the test is that you can't go back to the question once you skip it or submit an answer, so either you notice it's pointless and skip or you're stuck with that question for a few minutes.

Is the scoring structured so that you can get more points from leaving a question blank than from selecting any of the answers? (That is, is it possible all answers are "wrong" and the "correct" response is "none of the above," which you signify by not selecting any choice?) Maybe then part of the test is to recognize garbage questions and refuse to answer them.
